# webpack froala Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined #1312

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
{ 
    test: require.resolve("./src/plugins/froala_editor.min"),
    loader: "imports?$=jQuery"
}

var $ = require("jquery");
```

webpack chrome console error : `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).editable is not a function`

Comment: Give us more detail to answer your question.
Where is your code placed? All in `webpack.config`? Only loader object is in `webpack.config`? Do you have `var $ = require("jquery");` in `webpack.config`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/futakaposa/edit?html,css,js,console,output   my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding jQuery and webpack config you can do this :

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})
```

so when you use $ or jQuery in ur froala editor it will load jquery.

In ur case froala is using jquery UI before it loads jquery

OR!!
UPDATE:

```
npm install --save-dev script-loader
```

main.js

```
require('jquery')
require("script!./path-to-froala-editor.min");
```

OMG!! you have froala on npm just install it from there and require it in ur main.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/froala-editor

Comment: with ProvidePlugin you don't need to require jquery, also for external scripts use script-loader e.g require('script!path-to-froala');

https://github.com/webpack/script-loader

Comment: Code does not work ！error: Froala requires jQuery, can you help me!

Comment: Ok, try this in ur main.js require('jquery'); and then require("script!./file.js");
Take a look at update on answer!

Comment: error ! froala require jquery,why I do not know,thank you help!

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-froala-wysiwyg) and make sure you have added `Jquery min js file` in your `angular json` add `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` under script

Answer (score 0):

to complement @Shailendra Tiwari's answer, I do the same thing with the **imports-loader** webpack tool, I imported my library like this:

```
import 'imports-loader?window.jQuery=jquery!icheck';
```

notice how I didn't use `import 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery!icheck';`, that doesn't work because that library only looks in `window.jQuery`